New sod fertilizer St. Augustine
New St. Augustine sod was installed one month ago. I live in southwest Florida. Garden centers are recommending 19-0-19 or 16-0-8 or milorganite monthly. This seems to be an issue with phosphorus for St Augustine. A neighbor used lawnifi 888.
Looking for suggestions as I notice an inconsistency (Phosphorus or no phosphorus ). When I pick up mulch at garden center I notice landscaper flat beds with sod and milorganite loaded.

Milorganite is 6-4-0 see https://www.milorganite.com/faq

A soil test is what you need to choose a fertilizer (and other soil amendments.) Without a soil test you are just flinging things with no information. That is a best a waste of money, and at worst you can kill or damage the lawn.

Welcome to the site, and good luck with your new lawn!

You have two options.
The first option is to get a soil test and know exactly what your soil needs, and then add that.  Soil testing is affordable and easy.
The second option is to make blind guesses based on what St. Augustine sod might sometimes usually need.  Texas A&M published Maintaining St. Augustinegrass Lawns which also urges a soil test, but offers guidance even without one.

MARCH through MAY Fertilizing
Begin fertilizing 3 weeks after the grass turns green and when there
is little chance of a late frost. Apply 1 pound of soluble nitrogen
per 1,000 square feet of lawn every 8 weeks, or 1
1/2 pounds of slow-release nitrogen every 10
weeks. Have your soil tested to determine what added nutrients your
lawn may need. For information on soil testing procedures, contact
your county Extension agent.
If you do not have the soil tested, use a complete fertilizer with a 3-1-2 ratio of nitrogen, phosphorus and potassium (Examples:
15-5-10, 21-7-14, etc.).
JUNE through SEPTEMBER Fertilizing
Continue the fertilizer program begun in the spring, applying 1 to 1
1/2 pounds of nitrogen per 1,000 square feet
every 8 to 10 weeks. Without soil test information, it is
recommended that you use a fertilizer that either contains nitrogen
only (21-0-0, ammonium sulfate) or is low in phosphorus (Examples:
21-3-6 or 15-0-15) to reduce the chance of excessive phosphorus
build-up in the soil. Such build-ups can lead to deficiencies in iron
and zinc. To prevent yellowing caused by iron chlorosis, apply liquid
or granular iron fertilizer throughout the growing season. Follow the
label directions for the rate of application. Fertilizers containing
iron may stain concrete, brick or stone surfaces.
SEPTEMBER through FEBRUARY Fertilizing
Continue fertilizing as recommended until 4 to 6 weeks before the
first expected frost. At that time, apply a low nitrogen,
high-potassium fertilizer such as 5-10-10. Apply no more than
1/2 pound of nitrogen per 1,000 square feet.
Do not fertilize St. Augustinegrass from December through February
unless the lawn has been overseeded (planted with cool-season grass to
maintain its green color in the winter). Fertilize overseeded lawns
once in December and again in February with 1 /2 pound of nitrogen per
1,000 square feet, using a nitrogen-only fertilizer such as 21-0-0.
Have the soil tested to determine the nutrients needed. In the absence of a soil test, use a complete fertilizer with a 3- 1-2 ratio
of nitrogen, phosphorus and potassium.

